# Prove the relation $R = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}: \text{ |x|< |y| or x=y} \}$ is antisymmetric.

Tags: proof-verification, relations

> Prove the relation $R = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}:
>  \text{  } |x|< |y|\text{ or $x=y$} \}$ is antisymmetric.

Proof:

Suppose $ x R y$ and $ yRx $. Then 
 $|x|<|y|$ or $x=y$. Moreover, $|x|>|y|$ or $y=x$.

Case $|x|<|y|$:

Then because $yRx$, $x=y$.

Case $x=y$: Done.

In either case we showed $x=y$; hence, $R$ is antisymmetric.

---

Is the above proof correct?

Comment: Not quite.  Case 1: $|x|<|y|$ does not imply that $x=y$.  Afterall, if $x=y$ how is it possible that $|x|<|y|$?

Comment: @JMoravitz Do you have any other suggestions how to tackle this proof? In my book, it says it's antisymmetric.

Comment: It is indeed antisymmetric.  You should arrive at the conclusion that the first case you mention is an impossibility and derive a contradiction.  What does it mean for $|x|<|y|$ and for $|y|<|x|$?  Is it possible for a number to be strictly smaller than itself?

Comment: @JMoravitz How about this: Case |x|<|y| : Because y R x, x=y, but |x|< |y|, a contradiction. So, $|x| \ge |y|$. Now because y R x, x=y.

Comment: You say "Because y R x, x=y" but... that is not what is implied.  y R x implies that **either** $|y|<|x|$ or that $y=x$.  However... in either of those cases you get that $|x|<\cdots$

Comment: One could start the following way: "Assume $xRy$ and $yRx$, and for contradiction, assume further that $x\neq y$." It might be a bit easier to tangle with the logic in that case.

Comment: @JMoravitz But doesn't  y R x mean|x|>|y|, or y=x. This is another way of saying $|x| \le |y|  \to x=y$. Now because our case assumes |x| < |y|, by modus ponens, x=y, a contradiction with |x|>|y|. So now our negated case is $|x| \ge |y|$. Then use x R y to conclude x=y.